# How to check if two given polynomials intersect and at what exact X value

Tags: polynomials

I have two polynomial equasions, is there a simple way to check if they intersect and if yes determine the exact X value of intersection. Right now i wrote an algorythm that simply bruteforces all the Xs from zero to some approximate intersection point, but i feel like there's a more simple solution.

Comment: One word: subtraction.

Comment: And then take roots. But, finding exact expressions for roots isn’t always possible

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersect at some value of $x$, that is saying that $f(x)=g(x)$ for some value of $x$.  That is saying that $f(x)-g(x)=0$ for some value of $x$.  You can treat $f(x)-g(x)$ as a polynomial itself... call it $h(x)$ if you like.  There are standard techniques to determine if there are any values for which $h(x)=0$ and what they are.  That is one of the main focal points of what is taught in elementary algebra.

Comment: How to solve for the values of $x$ such that $h(x)=0$?  You would have heard of things like the quadratic formula... that if $h(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ the values of $x$ such that $h(x)=0$ will be $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.  There exists a generalized [solution up to quartics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) (*though hardly anyone bothers memorizing it*)... however for quintics and above the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) shows that no such generic formula with radicals can exist and you might be stuck using numerical methods.

Comment: As an example, the polynomials $f(x)=x^3-2x^2+4x-21$ and $g(x)=x^2+2x-15$ have in common the root $x=3$. This is equivalent to the fact that the determinant of order $5=3+2$ $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&-2&4&-21&0\\0&1&-2&4&-21\\1&2&-15&0&0\\0&1&2&-15&0\\0&0&1&2&-15\end{array}\right|$$ be equal to $0$. I just wanted to give this pertinent result here which is not well known by beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple once you realize
you are actually solving for a value of x where both equations are equal, and then you can simply take the 2 functions, or graphs, and then put them in an equation where they are equal to each other. Now, you can solve for x or prove that there is no such solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).